# Sylius: Adding Translations for locale

Tags: symfony, translation, sylius

I'm using the `Sylius/Sylius` package for development and would like to serve my visitors with a Dutch interface. Not all strings are translated to Dutch, and some are done poorly. My question now is, without touching the `Sylius` bundles directly, what would be the best way to add/override translations?

Because I want to re-use these translations I'm writing my own Sylius "wrapper", which in its current approach extends the Sylius bundles and have their own `Resources/translations` folder. For example: `MyWebBundle` extends `SyliusWebBundle` through `getParent()` and has a `Resource/translations/messages.nl.yml` file containing Dutch strings.

I'm looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since translations are not related to bundles, but to domains, you can overwrite the translations from anywhere. Either from `app/Resources/translations/` or from your bundles `Resources/translations/` directory.

Unfortunately Sylius is correctly missing a translations domain and uses only messages, this is a little mess, but there is already a discussion on GitHub. Translations is a very living part in Sylius and can change evrytime.

Comment: It seems your sentence was cut-off halfway "dis-"

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your answer. Can you share a link to this discussion?

Comment: [#133](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/133) and [#794](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/794)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sylius is using crowdin for maintaining languages support. As I can see dutch is at 95% so you can edit or update translation there and they will be updated in core.

https://crowdin.com/project/sylius