# How do you override hardcoded translation defaults in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, translation, sylius

I'm trying to override messages such as 'sylius.meta.frontend_title', but then I realized that the translations for these messages aren't used since the default settings for the 'general' namespace are hardcoded/set in GeneralSettingsSchema.php (in CoreBundle) [see below for twig snippet from WebBundle's layout.html.twig]:

```
    {{ settings.title|default('sylius.meta.frontend_title'|trans) }}
```

where settings is obtained with a call to the twig function sylius_settings_all('general')， with 'general' as the namespace for the schema desired. How can I override what title is displayed on my store's frontend (along w/ the other translations that are set by default e.g. 'sylius.meta.frontend_description')?

Btw, I'm using the full sylius bundle, which includes all the bundles in one installment.

Comment: Did you try that?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983070/sylius-adding-translations-for-locale

Comment: Yes, which fails for the same reason that my translations defined in my bundle's Resources/translations/messages.en.yml fails. I was able to override another translation, but was confused as to why my translation overrides for some other messages (e.g. sylius.meta.frontend_title) weren't working. I came up with a workaround, but stackoverflow won't let me post an answer until 8 hrs after the time I posted my question. Thanks for the comment though, Ramy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 ways to do this:

1. [Override twig template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) where title is rendered.
2. Override `GeneralSettingsSchema` class (to change defaults).
3. Go to http://demo.sylius.org/administration/settings/general and change values.

Comment: Thanks @umpirsky for the follow-up. I eventually realized there were those 3 ways, but went with the first way I thought of.

This was what I was going to add as an answer:
The path I ended up going w/ was overriding the service definition for sylius.settings_schema.general. I created my own GeneralSettingsSchema.php that extended the original CoreBundle's GeneralSettingsSchema class. I passed it the translator service. I then overrode the buildSettings() method, calling setDefaults() on $builder and mapping e.g. 'title' to $this->translator->trans('sylius.meta.frontend_title').