# How to install sylius translation

Tags: symfony, sylius

I cloned sylius/sylius. Everything runs fine so far.
But I have no clue, nor found in the docs, how i can install a translation for sylius.

At the moment there are only the keys visible in by Admin-Backend.
Any hint?

Comment: `composer require sylius/translation-bundle` ?

Comment: "sylius/translation-bundle": "self.version" is already there by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways how to solve your issue:

## the right way

First all translations (except english) are done on crowdin
https://crowdin.com/project/sylius

Look there if your language is missing some translations and translate the missing strings.
These translated strings are merged to master every week, as of yesterday. 
So when they will be merged just update your sylius installation with 'composer update'

## the possible but not so great way

Another option, if you don't / can't wait. Copy the translation files inside your app/Resources//translations folder.
Add missing translations directly in the yaml files.
The keys for translation strings you can see in the debug panel, or by listing them with console command ...

These translation files are following standard way how symfony translates, strings, so for more information how to override translation you can look here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I starded going the right way, because i have no preasure in time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please see answers and comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989633/487878 . It will also lead you to https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/133, https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/794, https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/1080 . As I have not worked on Sylius translation I am not sure, but my belief is that you can copy the yml and keep on the `app/Resources/translations` as symfony is the underlying system. Good luck with your research.